# How to set ipv6 source address to "::0"?

Tags: ipv6

I want do a DAD (DuplicateAddressDetection) test. I need setting ipv6 source address to "::0", but when I call bind function, it sets address to link-local address instead of "::0".

How should I do setting address to "::0"?

Comment: You probably need to use a raw socket and construct the IP header yourself if you want to do things like that.

Answer (score 0):

i think what you are trying to do is to use the any (ipv4 equivalent is 0.0.0.0) or the unspecified address. in ipv6 0:0:0:0:0:0:0:0 is ::. [::]:80 mean any / all ipv6 address at port 80.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IPv6_address#Unspecified_address